# Maximising the expected sum of random variables below a given threshold

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand [the solution](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/robot-long-jump-solution/) to Jane Street's [Robot Long Jump](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/robot-long-jump-index/) puzzle.

The optimal strategy "waiting until a robot’s position was at least some threshold $x$ and then jumping" makes sense to me, however, I'm not sure what's behind $(x^3 - 3x + 2)e^x = 3x$ equation for the threshold value.

First of all, the solution of this equation $\sim0.416195355$ is not in vicinity of what [my numerical simulation](https://github.com/ul/robot-long-jump/blob/main/src/main.rs#L18) produces ($\sim0.302$; the result fluctuates a bit from run to run).

Secondly, I fail to come up with the analytical solution that agrees with either Jane Street's equation or simulation. Here is my attempt:

Expected value of the jump after a single wait is $\int_x^{1}t\,dt=\frac{1-x^2}{2}$ as PDF for uniform distribution is $1$. Expected value of the waiting further is harder to calculate as it gets recursive. I tried using Irwin-Hall PDF with increasing number of steps but I reckon this is wrong:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_x^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\, tdt=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}(1-x^2)}{2(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{2}(e^x-1)(1-x^2)$$
which then leads to the equation $\frac{1-x^2}{2}=(e^x-1)\frac{1-x^2}{2}$ or $x = \ln(2) \approx 0.69315$.

What's the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: The 0.302 from simulation, is actually a solution to maximising $e^x (1-\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x}{2})$. This is what you will get if you do the Irwin hall diligently. However, this expression maximises the score, which is not the same thing as maximising payoff (technically). I am unable to understand the solution as well, but at least your simulation makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know if this is the most efficient approach but here is my solution. Rather than maximising a given Robot's expected score, we want to maximise their probability of winning (payoff), which is also dependent on the other Robot's strategy.

First, we can derive the cumulative distribution function of Robot i’s stopping sum $s_i$ (given they adopt threshold $a$ as a strategy) using a similar approach to the one you proposed. For $a≤t≤1$ we have

$P (s_i \le t) = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{(t-1)}}{(t-1)!} = e^a (t-a).$

The derivative with respect to $t$ also gives us the probability density, which is simply

$p(s_i)=e^a.$

Now consider the game from Robot 1's perspective. The probability that Robot 1 wins choosing threshold $a$ given Robot 2 chooses threshold $b$ (which Robot 1 knows) is

$M_1 (a,b) = \begin{cases}
  \int_b^1 \int_a^1 p(s_1,s_2) F(s_1,s_2) ds_1 ds_2 + P(s_2 > 1)(P(s_1 \le 1) + P(s_1 > 1) M_1 (a,b)), & \text{if } a < b \\
  \int_a^1 \int_b^1 p(s_1,s_2) F(s_1,s_2) ds_2 ds_1 + P(s_2 > 1)(P(s_1 \le 1) + P(s_1 > 1) M_1 (a,b)), & \text{if } a > b
\end{cases}$.

Where $P()$ and $p()$ are as defined above, and noting that $p(s_1,s_2)=p(s_1)p(s_2)$ since $s_1$ and $s_2$ are independent. And where

$F(s_1, s_2) =
\begin{cases}
  \frac{(s_1 - s_2 + 1)^2}{2}, & \text{if } s_1 < s_2 \\
  1 - \frac{(s_2 - s_1 + 1)^2}{2}, & \text{if } s_1 > s_2
\end{cases}$

is a function that returns the probability that Robot 1 wins given the stopping sums $s_1$ and $s_2$. Ie. the probability that $(s_1 + X) - (s_2 + Y) >0$ with $X, Y \sim \mathcal{U}(0, 1)$

EDIT: Why does $M_1(a,b)$ also appear on the RHS?

To make this clearer, let's alter the notation slightly. Change the $M_1(a,b)$ term on the LHS to be $M_{1,t=1}(a,b)$, the probability that Robot 1 wins *starting from* the first round (it should be clear that $M_1(a,b)=M_{1,t=1}(a,b)$ Ie. the probability of winning overall is equal to the probability of winning starting from the first round). Also, let $E_i$ be the event that round $i$ ends in a draw. Following this new notation, we would alter the $M_1(a,b)$ term on the RHS to be $M_{1,t=2|E_1}(a,b)$. So the first round ends in a draw with probability $P(s_2>1)P(s_1>1)$, and we multiply that by the probabiliy that the Robot 1 wins starting from the second round given the first round has ended in a draw, all in all giving us the term $P(s_2>1)P(s_1>1)M_{1,t=2|E_1}(a,b)$. But, the probability of winning from the second round (given that the first round has ended in a draw) is exactly the same as winning from the first round, since rounds are independent. Hence we can change the term $M_{1,t=2|E_1}(a,b)$ on the RHS to $M_{1,t=1}(a,b)$, giving us $M_{1,t=1}(a,b)$ on both sides of the equation. And as we noted before $M_{1,t=1}(a,b)$ is just the probability of winning overall $M_1(a,b)$.

Computing the integrals and probabilities above, and rearranging, we can get the (rather unruly) payoff to Robot 1 solely in terms of $a$ and $b$

$M_1(a, b) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{1 - (1 - e^a(1-a))(1 - e^b(1-b))} \left(\lambda + (1 - e^b(1-b))e^a(1-a)\right) & \text{if } a \leq b \\\\
\\\\
\dfrac{1}{1 - (1 - e^a(1-a))(1 - e^b(1-b))} \left(\theta + (1 - e^b(1-b))e^a(1-a)\right) & \text{if } a > b
\end{cases}$

where

$\lambda = -\dfrac{e^{a+b}}{12} \left(b^4 - 2(2a+2)b^3 + (3a^2 + 6a - 3)b^2 - 2(2a^3 + 6a^2 + 6a - 10)b + 2a^3 + 3a^2 + 2a - 6\right)$

$\theta = -\dfrac{e^{a+b}}{12} (a-1) \left(2b^3 + (3-3a)b^2 + (2a^2 - 4a - 10)b - a^3 + a^2 + 4a + 6\right).$
​

Next, we can compute Robot 1's best response function by taking the partial derivative of $M_1(a,b)$ with respect to $a$ and setting it to zero. Consider the case when $a \le b$

$\frac{\partial M_1(a, b)}{\partial a} = -\dfrac{\left(\left(\left(\left(8b^2-12b+4\right)\mathrm{e}^b+8b-4\right)a^3+\left(\left(-3b^3+3b^2+3b-3\right)\mathrm{e}^b-3b^2+3\right)a^2+\left(\left(6b^3-30b^2+30b-6\right)\mathrm{e}^b+6b^2-24b+6\right)a+\left(b^5-9b^4+11b^3+5b^2-12b+4\right)\mathrm{e}^b+b^4-8b^3+3b^2+8b-4\right)\mathrm{e}^a+\left(4b^2-6b+2\right)\mathrm{e}^ba^3+\left(-3b^3+27b^2-33b+9\right)\mathrm{e}^ba^2+\left(\left(4b^4-16b^3+36b^2-20b-4\right)\mathrm{e}^b-12b+12\right)a+\left(-b^5+9b^4-11b^3-5b^2+12b-4\right)\mathrm{e}^b\right)\mathrm{e}^{a+b}}{12\left(\left(\left(\left(b-1\right)\mathrm{e}^b+1\right)a+\left(1-b\right)\mathrm{e}^b-1\right)\mathrm{e}^a+\left(b-1\right)\mathrm{e}^b\right)^2}=0$.

We know that, due to symmetry, at equilibrium both Robots will employ the same strategy, say $(x,x)$. We can therefore substitute $x$ for $a$ and $b$ in the above best response function. Doing so, and simplifying yields,

$-\dfrac{\left(x-1\right)^2\left(x+2\right)\mathrm{e}^x-3x}{6\left(x-1\right)\left(\left(x-1\right)\mathrm{e}^x+2\right)}=0.$

This equality is satisfied when the numerator on the LHS is zero, which is equivalent to the equation given in the official solution $(x^3-3x+2)e^x=3x$.

A unique root to this equation in $[0,1]$ can be computed numerically to be $x$ ~ $0.416195355$

Moreover, we can verify that this equilibrium is unique by deriving the full best-response functions for Robots 1 and 2, and observing that they intersect only once at $(x,x)$ in the $[0,1]$ interval.

Apologies for the long-winded derivations, hopefully there exists a more elegant approach!

Comment: Thank you so much for an elaborate explanation! It mostly makes sense to me, and the thing that escapes me is $P(s_1 > 1) M_1 (a,b)$ term.

$P(s_2 > 1) P(s_1 \le 1)$ is clear — the probability of Robot 1 winning because Robot 2 went over the line. But when they both go over the line $P(s_2 > 1) P(s_1 > 1)$ — it's a draw, isn't it? And why does $M_1 (a,b)$ appear here as well on the right hand side?

Comment: No worries - I've edited the post to add an explanantion for that, let me know if it makes sense!